# Camera intrinsic parameters in blender python

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

How to get the camera intrinsic parameters matrix? By intrinsic parameters, I mean the focal length and principal point. Thank you!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=Intrinsics%20camera%20python